# Add X axis title to grouped Vega-Lite barchart

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following [Vega Lite plot](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)

and I am trying to understand how to put some text across the xaxis to indiciate the units there. If I try to add a title to the x-axis itself it adds underneath each pair of bars, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this right, you want to show some text across X-Axis, the way it would have appeared without grouping the marks.

Using the `title` of `header` configuration in `column` should work.
`"header": {"labelOrient": "bottom", "title": "#Items", "titleOrient": "bottom"}`

[Updated Vega-Lite plot](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIDdkBTAd020hOQBMAXAC3IEYAGFgGinqLXtvIDMbTpADOtAE6wA1kXKRJAQ3iiADoolF4-AL7twuSAFsN08sAWxYAG1rJV5eAFdr1nQb0HI1RbUXnIeEUjOSxvX0UmSE88EwkzMIAjDUh9PC04amR4dCwcQzhrWAlzA1woFCJrankQyWRoVLLDWgBPVVCoeFgjbMVrJvK8UWh+zosJZVROgG1IAGIAJhYhAA5F1Kh5gDFtgFYhABFIAF13cpiCmycjeFKhqDaO+W7eoIG0ochK6vl5sGQtCIRlEAPgYDgKjQ8BC2kGX1ExX4WBmTBEiwAtAJNpAACwYvY4gBsGNYOKYTAA1KdPuUxOpoNlcmAOM08NxFNQiCU8pBrIpElUAPISYhwpKwWi0Ho4uy0aydBYASSBINlgIVIrFyKgiUl0qM0WalzwAA97l8norill3vC6YpTchRAF+YLrC6sIh+qIiCI7NBpJ6wN6PX7HhrOs5XCbDD8amE6qLGsbaVBWha6Vb5ABHJzKOW+ZD4ORpvCO50BVCihMhn1EWN4eN-MAAYQQomhsNoLuNHk+kAAJCNuCZ5HxaKpRBgAPQzkuoRQAOlQgPoTkSS+QsBnI+BinnREXGOsgKI84ES9xS5YS4AVoi7gOfH5fT3M1AX5FyDM2dg-3g-xniCYIQh2XZaDqaIAVASYNPIAAK-QKu+ZaGP87ZQqgMKQcGuIAOz4QAnH+jb-g8gEAqqoLZGBWE4eKUCYtiaGxEQ9SNGESGuOxLqsVsbbgdh3Z4fhiykWh+QPAsVHAjR4KQp2wmQfI+KEvxxjscmiHIbx9pfBhQkMe+WBESRDxkVJBmySBtGKRBjGQCSZIaXBnFQNxKF8TBMmYUpxnBkSuISX+Vl0kB1GgfZymORS1KuVp8FcbpqE+YZ9EieQiz4SFDxhehNnyXR-ndswCUcfIrYaNKKj6eFgkZbh5CEYsey5UM+WUcBRXRcZ8jMXVhhuZV1UdoNlF+Q5JlgAIiyrCw7XlJ1AndVFRmlWEanjbBiXuZAVUSDV3kUQJk0xdNrCLMFFmSWlhVrY1jnOSw22aRVYQHUdr3pSVTVYMROU3aFd2rXZ60qWEcWvcNH2jbVGk-VNwYCESgNDOcuAnB4IA6EAA)